# I can't update a data

Tags: php, yii2

I got a problem to update my data, I changed the "usuarios" form and it's controller to put domicilios-form fields in the usuarios form, there's no problem to create a data, but when I want to change something I see an error screen

I made these changes in usuariosController:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Usuarios();
    $domi = new Domicilios();
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $domi->load($this->request->post())) {
            if ($model->validate() && $domi->validate()) {
                if ($domi->save()) {
                    $model->domicilio = $domi->id;
                    if ($model->save()) {
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $model->loadDefaultValues();
        $domi->loadDefaultValues();
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'domi' => $domi,
    ]);
}

    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $domi = Domicilios::findOne(['usuarios_domicilio' => $model->domicilio]);
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    $assigment = AuthAssignment::find()->where(['domicilios_id'=>$domi->id])->one();        


    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $domi->load($this->request->post())) {
            if ($model->save()) {
                if ($domi->save()) {
                    $auth->revoke($model->domicilio);
                    $auth->assign($model->domicilio);
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is on the beginning of actionUpdate, What should I change?

Comment: 1.) did you check your 'enableSchemaCache' option? 2.) 'usuarios_domicilio' has to be a column of 'Domicilios'

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you add your `Usuarios` and `Domicilios` ActiveRecords? If you have configured the relations there, you should be able to use `$domi = $model->domicilio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I just made these changes:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $domi = Domicilios::findOne(['id' => $model->domicilio]);


    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $domi->load($this->request->post())) {
            if ($model->save()) {
                if ($domi->save()) {
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'domi' => $domi,
    ]);
}
```

I deleted auth elements because they caused the previous errors and I changed "usuarios_domicilio" for "id"